# How to process data from one table and isert it to another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, procedure

I want to insert values from one of my tables to another.

I have a following table:

```
  Act (
  id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type VARCHAR(20),
  Act_date DATETIME,
  place VARCHAR(20)  
  );
```

where type has 2 possible values: "birth" and "death". All the columns are already filled.
Now, I am trying to make a procedure or a function which would calculate the difference between Acts of type "birth" and acts of type "death" for a given time and put the results in a different table, something like:

```
  Population_Growth(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time DATE,
  place VARCHAR(20),
  result INT
  );
```

where result would be the difference between Acts of type "birth" and acts of type "death"

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can do an INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM in one query.

Comment: Do you have the SELECT statement done already?  Also, just thinking, but I don't get the ID field in Act.  How do you identify which two rows go together?  Shouldn't the ID be the same for birth and death and not an auto increment?  Maybe it should make more sense to have a birth date and a death date instead of one date field and two rows.

Comment: I was thinking of something like:
INSERT INTO Population_Growth (id, time, place, result) VALUES
((SELECT Act_date FROM Act), (SELECT time FROM Act), (SELECT place FROM Act), ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Act WHERE type = "birth") - (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Act WHERE type = "death")

Comment: You don't need all those SELECTs and the first few without WHEREs would result in multiple rows and inaccurate information.  Provide me so more context so I can help, does my suggestion make sense to you?  I'm not sure how you are putting the birth and death together.

Comment: I think you are right, and initially I had two tables: Birth_Act and Death_Act with the same columns as Act accept for "type" and I can go back to that. I can even change the column "result" in Population_Growth to 2 seperate columns: "number_of_births" and "number_of_deaths" However the problem is something you already mentioned - I don't know what WHERE condition  I should use so that I get the values for a certain time interval (would "WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR) FROM Act_date BETWEEN ... AND ....." be ok?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was too long to write in a comment, it's not an answer for your problem as it is now, but it is what I recommend.  Why not just have a column for birth and a column for death in the same table?  Personally I would do this:

```
  Act (
  id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  birth_date DATETIME,
  death_date DATETIME,
  place VARCHAR(20)  
  );

  Population_Growth(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  result INT
  );
```

Have ID as the primary key in both, ID as a foreign key in population growth.  You don't need anything else but the result in Population_Growth as you can refer to the ID in Act for the place.  Avoid duplicate data in SQL unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Then you can do an insert using the information from the Act table.  TIMESTAMPDIFF will return an integer of the difference between the two dates.  I'm not sure if you want years, months, seconds, etc.

```
INSERT INTO Population_Growth 
SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, death_date, birth_date) FROM Act 
WHERE death_date IS NOT NULL AND birth_date IS NOT NULL;
```